# C# DynamicInvoke TargetParameterCountException

Tags: c#, delegates, invoke

i've been searching a while now but i haven't found a solution for my Problem. I've got a class that stacks methods on a list and then calls them one by one.
Everything works fine with return values, Parameters or methods without Parameters. But if a method has a optional Parameter it doesn't work.

This is just a simple testing method:

```
static void TestMe(Int32 _wait = 5000)
{
    //Pretend to do stuff...
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(_wait);
}
```

I add the method to my stack with:

```
static StackHandler __handler = new StackHandler();

__handler.AddMethod(new Action<Int32>(TestMe));
```

The `AddMethod` method creates a new ListItem and adds it into an internal list to Keep track of all stacked methods.
Then the handler wants to call the method with:

```
private object invokeMethod(Delegate _method, params object[] _args)
{
    return _method.DynamicInvoke(_args);
}
```

I get a `System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException` in the `invokeMethod` method. I've also tried to call it without the `args` Parameter, same result.
If i add the method `TestMe` like this:

```
__handler.AddMethodAsync(new Action<Int32>(Method), 6000);
```

It just runs fine.

How can i get this to work with optional Parameters?

Comment: Optional parameters are handled by the compiler, not the runtime.  You cannot make this work.  Only way to get ahead is to make a list of Action (non generic) and pass lambdas that provide the argument(s).

Comment: Too bad to hear this, but thanks for your anwser. But again i've learnt somthing :)